# Sonar Unable to retrieve changelog: ***is not a working copy

Tags: git, maven, svn, jenkins, sonarqube

We have a build job in jenkins, and we integrated sonar in this job. But the build failed after we migrated source code to git from svn. Errors like below:

```
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Can not execute Sonar

    Embedded error: Unable to retrieve changelog: svn: E155007: '*' is not a working copy

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Trace
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:103)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to retrieve changelog: svn: E155007: '*' is not a working copy

        at org.sonar.plugins.scmactivity.Changelog.retrieveChangeSets(Changelog.java:105)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scmactivity.Changelog.load(Changelog.java:55)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scmactivity.ScmActivitySensor.analyse(ScmActivitySensor.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:143)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:115)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:110)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:105)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:109)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:59)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98)
        ... 21 more
```

I've tried to wipe out the workspace, and also I've tried to disable the sonar plugin and then enable it as some of solutions in internet mentioned, but issues still exist.

I'm really stuck with it. Does any one have some good ideas?

Comment: Don't really have an answer but your error is coming from svn.  Looks like you're passing a shell meta as a path that you expect to be expanded.  Usually this means either the character is escaped or quoted when you aren't expecting that or your command isn't running through a shell.

Comment: @Ben Reser "*" is just a replaced chracters, it's a real path in fact. I think the point is why sonar recognized the git dir as svn dir and then execute svn command, so we get the error above.

Comment: Does your git directory happen to also have a .svn dir in it?

Comment: @Ben Reser Nope. We have fixed it by upgrading the SCM Activity plugin to version 1.6 in sonar. Thanks!

Comment: You should provide your own answer then.  So if someone else runs into the same problem they can fix it themselves.

Comment: @Ben Reser As below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed it by upgrading SCM Activity plugin in Sonar, from version 1.3 to version 1.6. As the issue tracker of SonarQube Plugins said, this issue has been fixed in SCM Activity 1.4.

Details here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS/fixforversion/17309

About SCM Activity plugin of Sonar: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin

I have found the solution before, but I just didn't understand it's upgrading the Sonar's plugin but not Jenkins' plugin and then this issue made me stuck.